# JSON to usable array javascript

Tags: json

I'm trying to convert my JSON code to a usable array in javascript/jquery.

I have the following JSON code arriving via ajax:

```
[{"id":"9","firstname":"Greg","surname":"Bril","position":"0","busy":"0","disabled":"0"},{"id":"14","firstname":"Nai","surname":"Brooks","position":"1","busy":"0","disabled":"0"},{"id":"17","firstname":"Margaret","surname":"Grey","position":"1","busy":"0","disabled":"0"},{"id":"1","firstname":"Cameron","surname":"Grover","position":"0","busy":"0","disabled":"0"},{"id":"2","firstname":"Sarah","surname":"Grover","position":"0","busy":"0","disabled":"0"},{"id":"3","firstname":"Margaret","surname":"Hynes","position":"0","busy":"0","disabled":"0"},{"id":"4","firstname":"Stephen","surname":"Hynes","position":"0","busy":"0","disabled":"0"},{"id":"11","firstname":"Ben","surname":"Mills","position":"1","busy":"0","disabled":"0"},{"id":"15","firstname":"Elizabeth","surname":"Mills","position":"1","busy":"0","disabled":"0"},{"id":"10","firstname":"Grant","surname":"Mills","position":"0","busy":"0","disabled":"0"},{"id":"16","firstname":"John","surname":"Mills","position":"1","busy":"0","disabled":"0"},{"id":"13","firstname":"Lucinda","surname":"Ower","position":"1","busy":"0","disabled":"0"},{"id":"12","firstname":"Karina","surname":"Scott","position":"1","busy":"0","disabled":"0"}]
```

It is created and intepreted using:

```
$.getJSON( "tc_search1.php", {
        leave: $("input#leave").val(),
        end: $("input#end").val(),
        override: $("#tc_override").is(":checked"),
        tc_id: $("#tc_id").val()
    }, function(data) {
         //i cant get this part to work
    });
```

I can't seem to manage to get the function on success to work. I tried the $.each method on jquery documentation website, but I can't get it right. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do `console.log(data)` and see how the data looks like.

Comment: Are you sure that the json you say you are returning is actually being recieved? - what is the contents of the data variable in your success function?

Comment: put a `debugger` statement in the callback and then open the chrome console.

Answer (score 0):

The `getJSON` method will automatically parse the JSON string into a Javascript object.

The `data` parameter in your success callback function will be an array of objects. For example, the expression `data[0].firstname` will return `"Greg"`.